# How can AuthForce be configured for scaling?

Tags: oauth-2.0, fiware, fiware-wilma

We are building an scenario where we are going to need more than 1 AuthForce using only 1 IdM. Can anyone help as to how we could configure this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You would set up a cluster of AuthzForce servers as described in the [High Availability section of AuthzForce Server documentation](https://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InstallationAndAdministrationGuide.html#high-availability). In short, configuration directories must be identical and data directories must be kept synchronized (using file sync solutions such as csync2 or distributed file systems such as NFS). Then you set up a HTTP or generic TCP load-balancing (e.g. HAProxy, apache+mod_proxy, nginx, etc.) with one or more load-balancers (sharing a virtual IP) in front of the cluster. Finally, in the IdM configuration, set the AuthzForce base URL (before the path info) to the URL of the load balancer(s), using the virtual IP or associated hostname if you use multiple load-balancers.